# CSS transition effect makes image blurry / moves image 1px, in Chrome?

Tags: css, image, hover, positioning, translate-animation

I have some CSS that on hover, a CSS transition effect will moves a div.

The problem, as you can see in the example, is that the `translate` transition has the horrible side effect of making the image in the div move by 1px down/right (and possibly resize ever so slightly?) so that it appears out of place and out of focus...

The glitch seems to apply the whole time the hover effect is applied, and from a process of trial and error I can safely say only seems to occur when the translate transition moves the div (box shadow and opacity are also applied but make no difference to the error when removed).

The problem only seems to happen when the page has scrollbars. So the example with just one instance of the div is fine, but once more identical divs are added and the page therefore requires a scrollbar the problem strikes again...

Comment: I'm on Chrome 27 on OSX, and it's fine. I believe that when the content gets put into a layer it gets turned into a bitmap during the animation, and that on older versions/older graphics cards this doesn't look great. Try a newer version and see if it's fixed.

Comment: Everything fine on Chrome 25 OS X. BTW: I'd suggest a different approach for the background gradient texture than a 300KB image!

Comment: And thanks @Paolo - the background image was for the demonstration only, it's not the image in use on the actual site!

Comment: The problem arise when the animation is handled by the GPU, looks like the bitmap roundings are a little bit off. Is reproduced in Canary, but it works ok if you turn off GPU acceleration

Comment: You can try this solution each frame... http://stackoverflow.com/a/42256897/1834212

Comment: I found that this issue only happen if the browser has a zoom. you can reset with CTR+0 / CMD+0

Comment: If your issue is `translateX/translateY` centering and you know the element dimensions, you can always fallback to the classic negative margin of half of the size of the centered element. and if your element is just `1px` at size just don't translate it doesn't make sense if you are already 50%-ing the 1px el :) .

Answer (score 276, accepted):

#### 2020 update

- If you have issues with blurry images, be sure to check answers from below as well, especially the `image-rendering` CSS property.
- For best practice accessibility and SEO wise you could replace the background image with an `<img>` tag using [object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) CSS property.

---

#### Original answer

Try this in your **CSS**:

```
.your-class-name {
    /* ... */
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1, 1);
}
```

What this does is it makes the division to behave "more 2D".

- Backface is drawn as a default to allow flipping things with rotate
  and such. There's no need to that if you only move left, right, up, down, scale or rotate (counter-)clockwise.
- Translate Z-axis to always have a zero value.
- Chrome now handles `backface-visibility` and `transform` without the `-webkit-` prefix. I currently don't know how this affects other browsers rendering (FF, IE), so use the non-prefixed versions with caution.

Comment: Might not have explained anything but it explained enough to fix this problem for me.

Comment: @Class Stacker - what's to explain? You just copy paste the code to your problematic element. Btw this works very nice!

Comment: Worked like a charm for me, even in Firefox :O

Comment: I can concur that this fixes a number of rendering issues even in Firefox (unprefixing, of course)... thanks rampapapa.

Comment: Sometimes problems caused by float width like 300.12px

Comment: @Rantiev, can you modify this fiddle so that the problem can be reproduced? What version of Chrome are you using?

http://jsfiddle.net/tf3xa/1/

Comment: @sampoh Hi, Do you work in Chrome team? Recently i found that Chrome latest versions contains less bugs related to float width and etc. but they are present. I can't find an example now, but will provide a link, if i bump with such an issue.

Comment: @Rantiev, no I don't but I'm flattered :P Just trying to find a better  solution for the problem.

Comment: @user1672694 you are right. Chrome does some image rendering and filtering. [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3pko74ze/) which shows the left side of the cat a little more sharper after some time the animation has stopped. Sometimes you notice a slight nudge in the image as well.

Comment: You may want to try SVG as well. Here is an example http://codepen.io/Izaias/pen/WvWxxv

Comment: Doesn't work with 'transform:translateY(-50%) translateZ(0)' and 'transform:translate3d(0, -50%, 0)'. Why?

Comment: @FredK you can only have one transform property, right?

This seems to work on my fiddle tests.
`.my-cat { -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; transform: translateZ(0) translateY(-50%) scale(1, 1); }`


`.my-cat:hover { transform: translateZ(0) translateY(-50%) scale(1.3, 1.3); }`

Comment: This worked for me, but I only used the backface-visibility portion. TranslateZ threw off my positioning. Thanks!

Comment: this works great but makes other elements such as paragraphs blurry. any ideas on how i fix it ?

Comment: @Double like Rantiev mentioned, it's the sub-pixels that cause this blur. And I believe that's the reason why the pixel shift happens in the first place.

Now you can try animation with font-size, that's looking good but is somewhat hard to handle.

Comment: @Rantiev "font-size animation" like what ? any links on the topic ?

Comment: This answer needs to include the non -webkit- property versions as well. Chrome disables the properties here and ignores them as invalid. It will now only accept the non-webkit variants.

Comment: @Routhinator I'd be happy to but... there's a possibility that it would make other browsers act weird, right? I don't have the time to test this now but if somebody can check that out then just ping me and I'll edit the non-vendor prefixed definitions there as well.

Comment: i suggest this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/42256897/1834212 im posting the link to avoid duplication

Comment: Can someone confirm if this still work, because whenever I add ` -webkit-backface-visibility` and `-webkit-transform`, I can't really see a change, and when I open chromes developer console. I see those 2 css properties are stroked through, as if they are overwritten, but they are not (empty css and html). It's as if chrome no longer accepts them.

Comment: @KevinM try without the -webkit- prefixes, these are now standard CSS.

Comment: This do not solve the issue. It actually make the whole content more blurred than before...

Comment: Do not use `translateZ(0)` if not necessary. It brokes DOM hierarchy model and isolates all childs from parent

Answer (score 99):

You need to apply 3d transform to the element, so it will get its own composite layer.
For instance:

```
.element{
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

or

```
.element{
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

More about layer creation criteria you can read right here: [Accelerated Rendering in Chrome](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/layers/)

---

**An explanation:**

Examples (hover green box):

- [Problem: Transition may cause blink effect on sibling elements (OSx Lion, Chrome 30)](http://codepen.io/sol0mka/pen/AcDFE)
- [Solution: An element on its own composite layer](http://codepen.io/sol0mka/pen/LlgJH)

When you use any transition on your element it cause browser to recalculate styles, then re-layout your content even if transition property is visual (in my examples it is an opacity) and finaly paint an element:

[image: screenshot]

The issue here is re-layout of the content that can make an effect of "dancing" or "blinking" elements on the page while transition happens.
If you will go to settings, check "Show composite layers" checkbox and then apply 3d transform to an element, you will see that it gets it's own layer which outlined with orange border.

[image: screenshot]

After element gets its own layer, browser just needs to composite layers on transition without re-layout or even paint operations so problem have to be solved:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: nice stuff! got a point cause of how detailed your answer was! which software you using for screen capturing / arrowing ?

Comment: Spot on mate!! Saved me a lot of hassle there.

Comment: This did the trick for me. At first I was using translateZ on the parent that I was animating, but the background-image sprites within were still blurry. I am using Velocity.js to scale yet another container within it and applied something like `translateZ: 0.000001` (some infinitesimal #) and voila! Sharp background-images once again!

Comment: Thanks mate. This worked on my problem. 
by the way, my problem is I have an element that is rotated 90degrees and has a fade-in transition using opacity. when triggering the transition the content of the element is moving 1px from left.

Answer (score 49):

Had the same problem with embeded youtube iframe (Translations were used for centering iframe element). None of the solutions above worked until tried **reset css filters** and magic happened.

**Structure:**

```
<div class="translate">
     <iframe/>
</div>
```

**Style [before]**

```
.translate {
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

**Style [after]**

```
.translate {
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  filter: blur(0);
  -webkit-filter: blur(0);
}
```

Comment: `filter: blur(0)` did it for me!

Comment: Unbelievable O_o
WTF with the blur ? Why's it on by default?

Comment: This was the solution for me too.  The accepted answer could work for people that aren't using other "translate" functions in their transform properties, but it wasn't working for me.

Comment: Shouldn't the `-webkit-` prefix come before? [More Info](https://css-tricks.com/ordering-css3-properties/)

Answer (score 36):

I recommended an experimental new attribute CSS I tested on latest browser and it's good:

```
image-rendering: optimizeSpeed;             /*                     */
image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;          /* Firefox             */
image-rendering: -o-crisp-edges;            /* Opera               */
image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast; /* Chrome (and Safari) */
image-rendering: optimize-contrast;         /* CSS3 Proposed       */
-ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor;   /* IE8+                */
```

With this the browser will know the algorithm for rendering

Comment: This fixed my blurry rotated images while backface-visibility, blur(0), translateZ did not work for me. Thank you.

Comment: Fixed images in some use cases, made it horribly worse in some others :-) Interesting in any case!

Comment: Digged in deeper: `image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;` solves the issue on Chrome. However, images on other browsers, e.g. Firefox, get rendered much, much worse with the rendering option set. Therefore, I only use the WebKit directive, which also works on the Blink engine. Thanks!

Comment: In some cases it causes the images to be noticeably jaggy. Can't seem to find a sweet-spot in between the blurrier result and this one ~sigh~

Comment: It isn't `optimizeSpeed` anymore, but `pixalated` -> see on the [mozilla website](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/Image-rendering)

Answer (score 6):

Just found another reason why an element goes blurry when being transformed. I was using `transform: translate3d(-5.5px, -18px, 0);` to re-position an element once it had been loaded in, however that element became blurry.

I tried all the suggestions above but it turned out that it was due to me using a decimal value for one of the translate values. Whole numbers don't cause the blur, and the further away I went from the whole number the worse the blur became.

i.e. `5.5px` blurs the element the most, `5.1px` the least.

Just thought I'd chuck this here in case it helps anybody.

Comment: Thanks, this was the issue in my case - I was using translateY(-50%) which must have been evaluating to a decimal pixel value.

Answer (score 5):

I cheated problem using transition by steps, not smoothly

```
transition-timing-function: steps(10, end);
```

It is not a solving, it is a cheating and can not be applied everywhere.

I can't explain it, but it works for me. None of another answers helps me (OSX, Chrome 63, Non-Retina display).

https://jsfiddle.net/tuzae6a9/6/

Comment: In your fiddle is shaking like Parkinson's, but in my case worked.

Answer (score 2):

Scaling to double and bringing down to half with `zoom` worked for me.

```
transform: scale(2);
zoom: 0.5;
```

Comment: this does seem to work in chrome for images. unfortunately it also modifies any html you put it around too.

Answer (score 2):

Try `filter: blur(0);`

It worked for me

Comment: Worked for me too, Chrome 63, 64, and Vivaldi 1.13

Answer (score 2):

I've tried around 10 possibly solutions. Mixed them up and they still didn't work correctly. There was always 1px shake at the end.

I find solution by reducing transition time on filter.

This didn't work:

```
.elem {
  filter: blur(0);
  transition: filter 1.2s ease;
}
.elem:hover {
  filter: blur(7px);
}
```

Solution:

```
.elem {
  filter: blur(0);
  transition: filter .7s ease;
}
.elem:hover {
  filter: blur(7px);
}
```

Try this in fiddle:

```css
.blur {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  width: 100px; height: 100px;
  background: #f0f;
  margin: 30px;
  -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
  transition: all .7s ease-out;
  /* transition: all .2s ease-out; */
}
.blur:hover {
  -webkit-filter: blur(0);
}

.blur2 {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  width: 100px; height: 100px;
  background: tomato;
  margin: 30px;
  -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
  transition: all .2s ease-out;
}
.blur2:hover {
  -webkit-filter: blur(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="blur"></div>

<div class="blur2"></div>
```

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

For me, now in 2018. The only thing that fixed my problem (a white glitchy-flicker line running through an image on hover) was applying this to my link element holding the image element that has `transform: scale(1.05)`

```
a {
   -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
   backface-visibility: hidden;
   -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1.0, 1.0);
   transform: translateZ(0) scale(1.0, 1.0);
   -webkit-filter: blur(0);
   filter: blur(0);
}
a > .imageElement {
   transition: transform 3s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: Yes!  'blur(0)' fixes it for me in Chrome. Makes the image very slightly blurry on resize though but is less noticeable than the jump / resize

Answer (score 2):

None of this worked, what worked for me is scaling image down.

So depending on what size you want the image or what resoultion your image is, you can do something like this:

```css
.ok {
      transform: perspective(100px) rotateY(0deg) scale(0.5);
      transition: transform 1s;
      object-fit:contain;
}
.ok:hover{
      transform: perspective(100px) rotateY(-10deg) scale(0.5);
}

/* Demo Preview Stuff */
.bad {
   max-width: 320px;
   object-fit:contain;
   transform: perspective(100px) rotateY(0deg);
   transition: transform 1s;
}
.bad:hover{
      transform: perspective(100px) rotateY(-10deg);
}

div {
     text-align: center;
     position: relative;
     display: flex;
}
h3{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
     
.b {
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<center>
<h2>Hover on images</h2>
<div class="b">
<div>
  <img class="ok" src='https://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/preview-11.png'>
  <h3>Sharp</h3>
</div>

<div>
  <img class="bad" src='https://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/preview-11.png'>
  <h3>Blurry</h3>
</div>

</div>

</center>
```

The image should be scaled down, make sure you have a big image resoultion

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with blurry text but only the succeeding div was affected. For some reason the next div after the one that I was doing the transform in was blurry.

I tried everything that is recommended in this thread but nothing worked.
For me **rearranging my divs** worked. I moved the div that blurres the following div to the end of parents div.

If someone know why just let me know.

```
#before
<header class="container">
      <div class="transformed div">
          <span class="transform wrapper">
            <span class="transformed"></span>
            <span class="transformed"></span>
          </span>
       </div>
       <div class="affected div">
       </div>
     </header>

#after
<header class="container">
   <div class="affected div">
   </div>
  <div class="transformed div">
      <span class="transform wrapper">
        <span class="transformed"></span>
        <span class="transformed"></span>
      </span>
   </div>

 </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
filter: blur(0)
transition: filter .3s ease-out
transition-timing-function: steps(3, end) // add this string with steps equal duration
```

I was helped by setting the value of transition duration `.3s` equal transition timing steps `.3s`

Answer (score 0):

The blurring occurred for me in Chrome only (Windows and Mac) when animating 'transform' in a keyframe animation. For me, the -webkit-optimize-contrast setting only partially helped. For best results I also had to use a "magic value" for scaleX (slightly larger than 1 instead of 1).

Here's the code that worked:

```
img {
  image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;
}

@keyframes scale-in-left {
  0% {
    transform: scaleX(0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleX(1.000001);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Here's the code that didn't work (caused blurry images in Chrome):

```
@keyframes scale-in-left {
  0% {
    transform: scaleX(0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleX(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

In the end, the "working" code removed most of the blurring, but not all of it. Safari and Firefox were still clearer without any special settings.

Note also that just resizing the browser window cleared up the unwanted blurring, suggesting perhaps that something is causing Chrome to fail to execute a final render pass (?).