# CSS Transition causing images in <a> tags to jump in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, css, css-transitions

I have a CSS3 transition opacity on a image responsive image (max-width: 100%) contained in  tag, on hover it changes size fractionally and then goes back to normal, when you remove the cursor it again does the same adjustment, I can't see anything which would cause this to happen. Using the chrome inspector turning styles off and on it vanishes when either opacity or the transitions are toggled off

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: see my answer here, could be useful. Failing that, provide code ! [http://stackoverflow.com/q/15657496/1926369]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first see this answer [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15464055/css-transition-effect-makes-image-blurry-moves-image-1px-in-chrome)

The second, try to check element width, if it's 300.12px (float number width), try to fix width so it would be rounded.

Sometimes this problem dissapear after applying position:relative to the image.

Chrome has bugs. So there could be other solutions, and problems with that. It might be so, your case has no solution. Like round corners + zoom animation.

Comment: Thanks for the help! The link in your answer was correct - this solved it placed onto the image and its surrounding a tag:
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1.0, 1.0);

Comment: Any time, i'm glad you have fixed it.