# Text "nudging" itself after css animation

Tags: html, css, firefox, animation, transform

I'm having trouble making my animation rotate smoothly. After the element finishes rotating, you can see the text "pop" slightly to the left. Depending on the font-size this may or may not happen, but I'm hoping to find a way to solve this without having to set an exact font-size (because the fallback fonts are not the same size and will have the same problem). It also depends on the browser, it appears ok in Chrome, but in FireFox you can see this clearly.

Try this in FireFox: http://jsfiddle.net/SGVNr/ Can you see the text nudge left (on the bottom box)?

```
div {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 30px;
    background: blue;
    font: 29px/100px Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}

#good {
    font-size: 30px;
}

div:hover {
    -webkit-animation: move 0.7s ease-out forwards;
    -moz-animation: move 0.7s ease-out forwards;
    animation: move 0.7s ease-out forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes move {
    0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); }
}

@-moz-keyframes move {
    0% { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { -moz-transform: rotate(90deg); }
}

@keyframes move {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(90deg); }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you remove the ID from the top and give it to the bottom it fixes the problem. Therefore, give both elements `font-size:30px` using a class it fixes your issue

[**Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/SGVNr/1/)

**EDIT**

After a good bit of investigation and testing, I found that 21, 22, 25, 27, 30, 33, 34, 36, 39, 41, 43, and 45px font-size (I only tested 20-45px) all worked as you want them to with no jump left after the rotation. This behavior was true no matter what other attributes I added/removed from the style. This hints to me that it is due to some weird rendering issue with Firefox You might report it on [the Firefox forums](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewforum.php?f=9)

Comment: I'm still experiencing problems after changing font-size and line-height, even if the font-size is larger than the original div's.

Comment: Try this for example: http://jsfiddle.net/SGVNr/2/ For some font sizes it works for some it doesn't.

Comment: Interesting, I still see the text nudge. I'm on FireFox 24.

Comment: In the example you posted without changing anything you're still seeing a nudge? I updated to 24 and I don't see it. Perhaps try clearing your cache? Not sure why it'd cache something like that, but perhaps it did. And try reopening the tab perhaps

Comment: In http://jsfiddle.net/SGVNr/2/ I see both boxes nudge the text. I cleared cache and opened in new tab.

Comment: Yep, I'm not seeing it. You're meaning a 3-5px shift of the words left after the rotation, correct?

Comment: That's correct. I asked a few other people to check to make sure, and they also see the text shift to the left by 2 or 3 px.

Comment: @Sunny It acts as you described on my other computer. This is quite a particularly weird issue, I'd recommend posting on the Firefox forums about it. I updated my answer as well

Comment: @Sunny Did you ever end up resolving the issue? I'm curious

Comment: I haven't tested this thoroughly, but I believe I found a solution by adding ``filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");`` to the rotated element. http://jsfiddle.net/SGVNr/3/. Note: If the element isn't rotated the filter will blur the text, but this should be easy to work around by only applying the filter when you rotate.Here's another example before filter: http://jsfiddle.net/42y89/ After: http://jsfiddle.net/42y89/2/

Comment: @Sunny know this is a old question but care to explain (if you know or how you found out) why this filter does the trick?

Comment: somehow `filter: blur(0);` works also, found it in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28565387)

Comment: I'm guessing that filters force Firefox to pay more attention and get the rendering right