scale with transformY moves element in the wrong direction
I try to animate the small bubbles in my svg. But when scale is applied it looks like it's applied to the distances between the bubbles rather than the bubbles only. It makes the buble to move to the side rather then up only as I'd like them. Why? And how to fix it? The transform-origin only changes the direction all of them moves.


svg {
position: absolute;
left: 200px;
top: 200px;
overflow: visible;
}

@keyframes bubble {
        0% {
            opacity: 1;
            transform: translateY(0) scale(1);
        }
        50% {
            opacity: 1;
            transform: translateY(-50px) scale(0.5);
        }
        100% {
            opacity: 0;
            transform: translateY(-100px) scale(0);
        }
    }

#circle1,
#circle2,
#circle3,
#circle4 {

transform-origin: top;
  animation: bubble 4s ease-in-out infinite;
}
<svg width="500" height="1000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle id="circle1" cx="30" cy="30" r="10" fill="red"/>
  <circle id="circle2" cx="70" cy="30" r="10" fill="blue"/>
  <circle id="circle3" cx="30" cy="70" r="10" fill="green"/>
  <circle id="circle4" cx="70" cy="70" r="10" fill="yellow"/>
</svg>




Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27635272/css3-transform-order-matters-rightmost-operation-first which discusses the order of transforms.

Update
You can use transform-box: fill-box to make the circles behave like HTML elements


svg {
  contain: paint;
}

circle {
  animation: bubble 4s ease-in-out infinite;
  transform-box: fill-box;
  transform-origin: 50%;
}

@keyframes bubble {
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(-50px) scale(.5);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-100px) scale(0);
  }
}
<svg width="100" viewBox="0 -100 100 200">
  <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="10" fill="red"/>
  <circle cx="70" cy="30" r="10" fill="blue"/>
  <circle cx="30" cy="70" r="10" fill="green"/>
  <circle cx="70" cy="70" r="10" fill="yellow"/>
</svg>




Old answer
transform-origin: top sets the transform origin to the middle of the top edge of the <svg> element (in your case 250px 0), so all transforms happen in relation to that point. You probably want something like this:


svg {
  background: pink; /* visualize bounds */
  margin-top: 100px;
  overflow: visible;
}

@keyframes bubble {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0) scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(-50px) scale(0.5);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-100px) scale(0);
  }
}

circle {
  animation: bubble 4s ease-in-out infinite;
}


/* solution 2 */
#circle1 { transform-origin: 30px 30px }
#circle2 { transform-origin: 70px 30px }
#circle3 { transform-origin: 30px 70px }
#circle4 { transform-origin: 70px 70px }
<!-- solution 1 -->
<svg width="100" height="100">
  <g transform="translate(30, 30)">
    <circle r="10" fill="red"/>
  </g>
  <g transform="translate(70, 30)">
    <circle r="10" fill="blue"/>
  </g>
  <g transform="translate(30, 70)">
    <circle r="10" fill="green"/>
  </g>
  <g transform="translate(70, 70)">
    <circle r="10" fill="yellow"/>
  </g>
</svg>

<!-- solution 2 (see css) -->
<svg width="100" height="100">
  <circle id="circle1" cx="30" cy="30" r="10" fill="red"/>
  <circle id="circle2" cx="70" cy="30" r="10" fill="blue"/>
  <circle id="circle3" cx="30" cy="70" r="10" fill="green"/>
  <circle id="circle4" cx="70" cy="70" r="10" fill="yellow"/>
</svg>



You can then position the <svg> however you want.
If you want to optimize the rendering, you should avoid using overflow: visible and instead expand the SVG to accommodate for the animation, and maybe use contain: paint, like so:


svg {
  background: pink; /* visualize bounds */
  contain: paint;
  margin-top: -100%;
}

@keyframes bubble {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0) scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(-50px) scale(0.5);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-100px) scale(0);
  }
}

circle {
  animation: bubble 4s ease-in-out infinite;
}

/* example container */
div {
  display: grid;
  min-height: 180px;
  outline: pink solid;
  place-content: center;
}
<div>
  <svg width="50" height="100" viewBox="0 -100 100 200">
    <g transform="translate(30, 30)">
      <circle r="10" fill="red"/>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(70, 30)">
      <circle r="10" fill="blue"/>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(30, 70)">
      <circle r="10" fill="green"/>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(70, 70)">
      <circle r="10" fill="yellow"/>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>



Here we're "raising the ceiling" in the <svg>, and lowering it again with margin-top: -100%, so the image can be centered properly. You can also scale the SVG using width/height, as long as you provide a viewBox

That would work, but I've got a much larger image and I have just created this one to illustrate the problem. In reality I've got almost 80 bubbles, I'm not sure if I setting transform-origin separately for each bubble is viable. I don't understand why transform-origin: top sets the point at the top of my svg rather than the element that this is set at, but I get that there is no other way to do it?

SVG transforms work a little differently than HTML+CSS transforms. But I just remembered transform-box: fill-box was a thing, see the updated answer :)

It's because of the scale but also width and transform-origin play part. Most the of issues are resolved when the width is indeed 100. Also, you can make the transform-origin: left to make it appear to stay on same x position. Besides you can apply the transform to the entire svg rather than it's inner circles.


svg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 100px;
  overflow: visible;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

@keyframes bubble {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0) scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(-50px) scale(0.5);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-100px) scale(0);
  }
}

svg {
  transform-origin: top center;
  animation: bubble 4s ease-in-out infinite;
}
<svg width="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle id="circle1" cx="30" cy="30" r="10" fill="red"/>
  <circle id="circle2" cx="70" cy="30" r="10" fill="blue"/>
  <circle id="circle3" cx="30" cy="70" r="10" fill="green"/>
  <circle id="circle4" cx="70" cy="70" r="10" fill="yellow"/>
</svg>



