# Text gets Blured during transition

Tags: html, css

On hovering Text gets blured(on Chrome).
I know this is because of **SCALING of text**..
So my question is is there any way to do the same task in which text doesn't get blured.
Here is what I have tried

```css
span a {
  font-size: 24px;
}
span:hover a {
  color: #ba4a49;
  -webkit-transform: scale(10);
  transition: all 2s linear;
}
```

```html
<span>
    <a href="#">Hello this looks blured during transition</a>
</span>
```

**update**
Plese Note that I have to scale the text from center. If I change the font Size 10 Times then scaling is done from left(not center)

```
span:hover a {
  color: #ba4a49;
  font-size:250px;
  transition: all 2s linear;
}
```

[See Updated](https://jsfiddle.net/be9o8tz9/3/) 
[Jsfiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/be9o8tz9/)

Comment: The text doesn't blur when my browser was fullscreened, just FYI.

Comment: Just set `span a font-size` to `100%`

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15472358/757839)?

Comment: Yes I did not solve my problem

Answer (score 3):

To prevent blurring, you can transition on `font-size` instead of on `transform: scale`. For what it's worth, I didn't experience any blurring problems with your example on my own Chrome browser.

**Live Demo:**

```css
span a{
    font-size: 24px;
}
span:hover a{
    color:#ba4a49 ;
    font-size: 240px;
    transition: all 2s linear;
}
```

```html
<span><a href="#">Hello this looks blured during transition</a></span>
```

Comment: I didn't notice any blurring either until I resized my browser window much smaller (Google Chrome, Windows 8.1, latest)

Comment: I don't think so that your way can be a replacement of scaling, need more css trick to simulate it

Comment: in my screen Text gets blured .. Changing font size will not solve my one problem.. I need to scale from the center.. scaling axis needs to be defined.. How to do this?

Comment: @HosseinShahsahebi It depends entirely on the use case. For some use cases this will be a suitable replacement as-is, for other use cases it will need some extra CSS.

Comment: @Vishu238 If you don't mind using a tiny bit of JavaScript, here is a way that you can get `font-size` to scale from the center: https://jsfiddle.net/be9o8tz9/5/