# Scaled text is blurry

Tags: html, css

Im scaling up text on hover by a small amount. The text looks blurry. After searching for a solution, I have tried various methods other people mention, but these do not work.

eg.

```
backface-visibility: hidden;
```

I've also tried scaling down the text before hover and using hover to scale to a value of 1. This also fails to work.

How can I scale text without it being blurry?

Im using transform scale and the bug is in webkit browsers

Comment: What browser are you using? Do you see the same behavior if you try a different browser?

Comment: Have you already try - transform-style: preserve-3d; -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d; This must be on the parent element.

Comment: What do you mean by scaling up? Are you changing the `font-size`? Are you using `transform: scale...`? Is your text in an HTML element, an SVG object or in a bitmap image? Please show some code.

Comment: Im using transform scale and the bug is in webkit browsers

Comment: Can you provide your code, both the HTML and CSS which is affected

Answer (score 0):

You can scale font-size. Please check

```css
span a{
    font-size: 24px;
}
span:hover a{
    color:#ba4a49 ;
    font-size: 240px;
    transition: all 2s linear;
}
```

```html
<span><a href="#">Hello this looks blured during transition</a></span>
```

Please check [This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32080802/text-gets-blured-during-transition)