# transform + transition causes jump or blurry content CSS

Tags: css, transform, transition

Let's start with the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r1kw37g5/

```
.grid-item .diamond .inner-diamond{
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
       -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
          transform: rotate(45deg);
  width: 394px;
  height: 394px;
  position: relative;
  top: -23%;
  left: -23%;
}
```

The situation is I created a diamond shaped grid.
This grid has elements in it that are rotated -45 deg and a container inside that is rotated 45 deg to get the content straight again. (the content appears on hover)

Inside that container is a button with a simple animation, and here is where the problem starts. When you hover over the button the other content becomes blurry for a while until the animation ends and also makes a 1px jump to the right.

I tried: putting a translateZ(0) on the container to stop it from making a jump. That works but makes the content blurry constantly. I have tried to combat the blurry content with zoom and scale combination preserve3d and font-smoothing but so far no luck.

The question is does anybody know a way in which I can animate the button without it making a jump and without the other content becoming blurry?

Comment: Have you checked if the opacity / color of the text changes during the animation with devtools? Because it looks like default color of the text is not the same as it is during the animation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems there are some problem in the animation ([CSS transition effect makes image blurry / moves image 1px, in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15464055/css-transition-effect-makes-image-blurry-moves-image-1px-in-chrome))

I'll let the text outside the `transform`'s element.

1. put your `.button` inside `.diamond`
2. move `.inner-diamond` to be a sibling of the `.diamond`, give it a `opacity: 0`(remove `.diamond-content`'s `opacity:0`)
3. set `pointer-events:none` to the `.inner-diamond`

use sibling method to fulfill it

```
.diamond:hover + .inner-diamond {
  opacity: 1
}
```

a quick demo(layout not pretty): 
http://jsfiddle.net/r1kw37g5/6/

Comment: This work around does cause new problems for my specific build, but the answer does explain the problem quite nicely and offers a practical work around so kudo's on that