# image blurs during CSS transition and is janky

Tags: html, css, transition

Hi I'm learning to create some hover effects and managed to pull off what I had in mind with this animation: http://jsbin.com/xawibo/

The CSS that animates the image is this:

`transform: scale(3, 3) translateY(50%);`

But the animation is not smooth. The thumbnail becomes blurry during the transition, becoming crisp again only when the transition stops. There is also a slight left/right jerky movement.

Here is a quick Youtube video of what I see:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yoIgV1ORbN8&feature=youtu.be

What am I doing that is affecting the perforamce of this animation? Am I nesting too many DIVs?

Comment: I don't think there's a way around the image blurring - during transition the image will blur, that's the nature of animating images. I would say this is something that the developer notices far more than the user - to me this animation looked great the first time, I had tow view twice to see the issue.

Comment: Are you viewing in Chrome? I forgot to mention I notice this in chrome and cannot test other browsers ATM.

Comment: Yes, chrome on a mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like Chrome specific issue.

Instead of `transform:scale()` you can animate `width`:

```
.caption:hover > span img{
  background: rgba(0, 158, 205, 0.45);
  transform: translate(0,10%) ;
  width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried it and it performs much better! However there is still a slight nudge to the right

Answer (score 1):

This happens on chrome on Windows apparently.

Seems very similar to the issue depicted here:
[CSS transition effect makes image blurry / moves image 1px, in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15464055/css-transition-effect-makes-image-blurry-moves-image-1px-in-chrome)

What happens when using `-webkit-transform: [...]` along with `transform: [...]` ?

Comment: Thank you I tried the fix from that other SO question but nothing happened. And I just tried using -webkit- no dice. I am on windows 10. I added a video of what I see in the original post.

Comment: I looked at the video, it's very similar to what I'm getting on chrome, both on Windows7 and Windows10.