# Blurry marker for google maps in google chrome

Tags: google-maps, google-chrome, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am using google maps in my application. I have custom markers being shown and all looks fine on Firefox as you can see in this image[image]

But then in chrome it is all blurry. The markers are blurry. Here you can see
[image]

I am adding makers like this

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location.position(),
    map: map,
    draggable: drag,
    icon: getLocationMarker(loc),
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
});

function getLocationMarker(loc) {
var icon = marker_icon_default;

if (!loc.organization().hasFancyMarkers()) // if the organization doesn't have fancy markers module
    return icon;

if (!loc.checkIfOrderHasRemainingAmount()) // if there is no remaining amount for the orders then we take the default icon
    return icon;

var hasTentativeMatches = loc.anyOrderHasPotentialMatches();

switch (hasTentativeMatches) {
    case true:
        icon = getIconWithTentativeMatches(loc);
        break;
    case false:
        icon = getIconWithoutTentativeMatches(loc);
        break;
}

return getImageMarker(icon);
}


function getImageMarker(icon) {
var image = {
    url: icon,
    // This marker is 40 pixels wide by 40 pixels high.
    size: new google.maps.Size(40, 40),
    // The origin for this image is (0, 0).
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    // The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at (15, 32).
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(15, 32),
    scale: 2
};
return image;
}
```

So basically chrome has tried to optimized google maps. They make a duplicate marker which you can see in the image below. The blurry one is the one I see and it is blurry because of the opacity is 0.01 on that one. The other is not visible at all. Hoping chrome will solve it soon.

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could try these css rules on the icons:

```
img.icon{  
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

but as far as I know, chrome has always had issues with scaling images. Firefox is considered to be quite a slow browser, which might have to do with why Firefox manages to render things more neatly.

The only solution I could tell you is to make sure the icons aren't scaled down. Make sure they are the right sizes and then avoid scaling them. (I personally use [timthumb](https://www.binarymoon.co.uk/projects/timthumb/) for this purpose, with PHP. You can still get images through javascript with it)

Then again, I might be wrong, I'm not a veteran. However, I'm at least 70% sure this is a browser thing which you can't really control.

Another thing you could try is the solution to this question:
[CSS transition effect makes image blurry / moves image 1px, in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15464055/css-transition-effect-makes-image-blurry-moves-image-1px-in-chrome)

Other than that, this really is just trial and error. I'm quite sure there is no definitive "This'll do the trick!" option in general.

Comment: Thanks for response, I have made an edit to the post and I guess I found out what was the issue.

Comment: ahhh alright. Whelp, this is quite often the case with google things. I hope it'll get fixed soon! Have had similar issues many times.

Answer (score 0):

in getImageMarker use not **size: ..** but

```
scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(xx,yy),
```