# Text & Icons appear blurry and move with css transform effect

Tags: html, css, blurry

So I've done a lot of researching regarding this problem especially going through and trying all of the stuff in this thread:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15464055/css-transition-effect-makes-image-blurry-moves-image-1px-in-chrome#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15464055/css-transition-effect-makes-image-blurry-moves-image-1px-in-chrome#_=_)

However, `filter:blur(0); transform:translateZ(0)` only work on laptop screens and not normal IPS flat screens. You still see the shifting and blurring of text. Does anyone have a solution that works for both laptop, normal monitors and across browser ? Below is an example of what happens on normal monitors, notice the shifting of the icons vertically. Below that is the code we're using.

### [image: issue happening on a normal monitor screen]

```
.article-catalogue {
  transition: transform .3s ease, box-shadow .3s ease,border .3s ease;
  filter: blur(0);
  image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;
  transform: translateZ(0);
}

.article-catalogue:hover {
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0) scale(1.02);
  box-shadow: 0px 12px 40px -10px rgba(51,51,51,.2);
}
```

One thought, could it be the rollover elements within the card causing the problem ?

Comment: You are changing perspective on hover. That might be the reason for movement.

Comment: ya.. even without perspective it does it. i tried all the different permutations and it constantly fails on normal monitors. laptop, especially mac screens it works fine :(