# Transition makes image shift 1px

Tags: css, hover, css-transitions, css-transforms

I've seen [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15464055/css-transition-effect-makes-image-blurry-moves-image-1px-in-chrome) but it doesn't work for me. (unless I was pasting suggested code in wrong place)

Basically, in Firefox, when hovering a link, the image under shifts 1px (only some of them, so please play around to catch it). Chrome, on top of that, blurs all images.

[See my Codepen](https://codepen.io/alanvkarlik/pen/PRMeJg)

When I delete

```
  -webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
```

the problem disappears.

Is there a way to make it work without losing that line?

Full code:

HTML

```
<div class="main">
        <div class="hover_img animated fadeInUp">
            <a class="hover_link" href="work/sensory/">Sensory Possibilities<span>
              <img src="http://witch-house.com/NEW/sensory.png"/></span></a>
            /
            <a class="hover_link" href="work/designing/">Designing Humans<span>
                <img src="http://witch-house.com/NEW/deshum.png"/></span></a>
            /
            <a class="hover_link" href="work/daggerforest/">Dagger Forest<span>
                <img src="http://witch-house.com/NEW/dagger.jpg"/></span></a>
            /
            <a class="hover_link" href="work/wavelength/">Wavelength<span>
               <img src="http://witch-house.com/NEW/dagger.jpg" class="img4"></span></a>
            / 
            <a class="hover_link" href="work/talescrypt/">Tales From The Crypt<span>
                <img src="http://witch-house.com/NEW/tftc.jpg"/></span></a>
            /
            <a class="hover_link" href="work/dnahackers/">DNA Hackers<span>
                <img src="http://witch-house.com/NEW/dnahx.jpg"/></span></a>
            /
            <a class="hover_link" href="work/robots/" >Do Graphic Designers Need To Be Human?<span>
                <img src="http://witch-house.com/NEW/robots.jpg"/></span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.main {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 54%;
  font-size: 2.5vw;
  line-height: 2.8vw;
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight:200;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.hover_link {
  color: #d2d2d2;
  font-family: 'Rubik';
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight:900;
}
.hover_link:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #4b2de5;
}

/* PROJECTS IMAGES */

.hover_img span {
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index:-1;
  opacity: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
}
.hover_img a:hover span {
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 1;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

a {  text-decoration:none; }
img { width: 40vw; }
```

Comment: are you sure you shared the correct codepen ?

Comment: umm, yeah, this one: https://codepen.io/alanvkarlik/pen/PRMeJg ? EDIT. yes it was wrong link - should be fixed now, apologies!

Answer (score 0):

try with this CSS

```
  .main {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 54%;
    font-size: 2.5vw;
    line-height: 2.8vw;
    font-family: 'Raleway';
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight:200;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

  .hover_link {
    color: #d2d2d2;
    font-family: 'Rubik';
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight:900;
  }
  .hover_link:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #4b2de5;
  }

  /* PROJECTS IMAGES */

  .hover_img span {
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    top: -50%;
    left: 0;
  }
  .hover_img a:hover span {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  a {  text-decoration:none; }
  img { width: 60%; margin: 0 auto;}
```

Comment: unfortunately in your example the images are not centered, plus Chrome is still blurry :(

Answer (score 0):

and changing the way we insert the image in the html in this way

```
    <div class="main">
         <div class="hover_img animated fadeInUp">
             <a class="hover_link" href="work/sensory/">Sensory Possibilities
                <span style="background-image: url(http://witch-house.com/NEW/sensory.png)" /> 
               </span></a>
                /
                <a class="hover_link" href="work/designing/">Designing Humans
                  <span style="background-image: url(http://witch-house.com/NEW/deshum.png)" /> 
                  </span></a>
                /
                <a class="hover_link" href="work/daggerforest/">Dagger Forest
                  <span style="background-image: url(http://witch-house.com/NEW/dagger.jpg)" /> 
                  </span></a>
                /
                <a class="hover_link" href="work/wavelength/">Wavelength
                  <span style="background-image: url(http://witch-house.com/NEW/dagger.jpg)" /> 
                  </span></a>
                / 
                <a class="hover_link" href="work/talescrypt/">Tales From The Crypt
                  <span style="background-image: url(http://witch-house.com/NEW/tftc.jpg)" /> 
                  </span></a>
                /
                <a class="hover_link" href="work/dnahackers/">DNA Hackers
                  <span style="background-image: url(http://witch-house.com/NEW/dnahx.jpg)"/>
                  </span></a>
                /
                <a class="hover_link" href="work/robots/" >Do Graphic Designers Need To Be Human?
                  <span style="background-image: url(http://witch-house.com/NEW/robots.jpg)"/>
                  </span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

and the CSS

```
.main {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 54%;
    font-size: 2.5vw;
    line-height: 2.8vw;
    font-family: 'Raleway';
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight:200;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

  .hover_link {
    color: #d2d2d2;
    font-family: 'Rubik';
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight:900;
  }
  .hover_link:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #4b2de5;
  }

  /* PROJECTS IMAGES */

  .hover_img span {
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    left: 0;
    top: -50%;
    height: 200%;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: auto 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
  .hover_img a:hover span {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  a {  text-decoration:none; }
  img { width: 60%; margin: 0 auto;}
```

Comment: that works better, but when I change the size of those images to bigger - they are getting cropped by the .main container - see: https://codepen.io/alanvkarlik/pen/WzVBzO

Comment: background-size: auto 100%; change to background-size: 100% auto ;

Comment: still cropped - this time with height