# Inner div oscillates when using a CSS transition on the parent div

Tags: flexbox, css-transitions

Please run my code sample and hover over the black square, why does the inner `div`, the white border `div`, oscillate/shake?  How do I make it stop doing that?

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

.main-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1;
}

.transition-container {
  background: black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 20px;
  transition-duration: 1.25s;
  transition-property: margin, width, height;
}

.transition-container:hover {
  margin: 0;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
}

.inner-container {
  border: 4px solid white;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="transition-container">
    <div class="inner-container">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Goal**

- On hover of my outer div (`<div class="transition-container">`), I want it to **grow** and I want to use a transition to make it **smooth**
- I don't want the growing `div` to take up any more space.  Currently, to achieve this, I shrink the margins

Comment: Some of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15464055/2341603) may be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `transition-timing-function: steps(10, end);` fixed my contrived example.  [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48232676/185123).

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

.main-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1;
}

.transition-container {
  background: black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 20px;
  transition-duration: 1.25s;
  transition-property: margin, width, height;
  transition-timing-function: steps(10, end);
}

.transition-container:hover {
  margin: 0;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
}

.inner-container {
  border: 4px solid white;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="transition-container">
    <div class="inner-container">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the border width from `4px` to `4.5px` on `<div class="inner-container">` fixed it.  Changing it to any decimal seems to fix it.  For instance if I use `5.5px` or `3.5px` that fixes it too.  I don't understand why though ‍♂️, would love to know why!

I had to use this fix in our application as the [`transition-time-function`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53106090/185123) fixed didn't work in our more complicated layout.

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

.main-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1;
}

.transition-container {
  background: black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 20px;
  transition-duration: 1.25s;
  transition-property: margin, width, height;
}

.transition-container:hover {
  margin: 0;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
}

.inner-container {
  border: 4.5px solid white;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="transition-container">
    <div class="inner-container">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```