# ReactJS - add momentum to scroll

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll

I created a component which allows for a drag and scroll functionality. The problem I have now is that I don't know how to add momentum to the scroll on mouse up (and also but that's not that important a bounce effect).
The important part is: How do I update a component over some period of time (depending how strong was the drag)?

Below my scroll component code:

```
class DraggingScrollView extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isScrolling: false,
      scrollLeft: 0,
      clientX: 0,
    };
    this.scrollContainer = React.createRef();
    this.handleMouseDown = this.handleMouseDown.bind(this);
    this.handleMouseUp = this.handleMouseUp.bind(this);
    this.handleScroll = this.handleScroll.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    const { isScrolling } = this.state;
    if (isScrolling !== nextState.isScrolling) {
      this.setScrollingEnabled(nextState.isScrolling);
    }
  }

  setScrollingEnabled(isEnabled) {
    if (isEnabled) {
      window.addEventListener('mousemove', this.handleScroll);
    } else {
      window.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.handleScroll);
    }
  }

  handleMouseDown(event) {
    const { clientX } = event;
    const { scrollLeft } = this.scrollContainer.current;
    this.setState({
      isScrolling: true,
      scrollLeft,
      clientX,
    });
  }

  handleMouseUp() {
    this.setState({
      isScrolling: false,
      scrollLeft: 0,
      clientX: 0,
    });
  }

  handleScroll(event) {
    const { scrollLeft, clientX } = this.state;
    const scrollContainer = this.scrollContainer.current;
    const scrollDestination = scrollLeft + clientX - event.clientX;
    scrollContainer.scrollLeft = scrollDestination;
  }

  render() {
    const { children, scrollContainerHeight } = this.props;
    return (
      <div
        id="scrollContainer"
        ref={this.scrollContainer}
        role="presentation"
        style={{ paddingTop: scrollContainerHeight }}
        onMouseDown={this.handleMouseDown}
        onMouseUp={this.handleMouseUp}
      >
        <div id="scrollContentContainer">{children}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you probably want to look into `requestAnimationFrame`, though user-scroll and strength of drag makes this more complicated. check here for an example.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54955894/smoothly-animate-a-div-as-its-position-changes/54958986#54958986