# Why is `transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0)` being applied to this css transition?

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-transforms

Yesterday I used a snippet of from [hover.css](https://ianlunn.github.io/Hover/). I know CSS well enough to understand what is going on here, **except one line**, which is `transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);`. I've tried to feed the exact values to [this demo on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translateZ), however, it gave me a crazy result. (I suspect that this is some kind of render sub-optimization (such as `transform: scale(0.99)`, which I slightly remember to have seen before), but I might be wrong. Or a stacking context?). Can anybody explain? Thanks.

```css
.hvr-underline-reveal {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0); /* <-- what is going on here? */
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}    

.hvr-underline-reveal:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #2098D1;
    height: 4px;
    transform: translateY(4px);
    transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
}

.hvr-underline-reveal:hover:before {
  transform: translateY(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="hvr-underline-reveal">You'll see a thick underline if you hover me</div>
<p>But do I really need perspective and Z axis transition? What is it good for?</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "useless" transformation in the Z-plane is often used to fix blurry rendering that occurs when translating or transitioning something or for some other reason force the browser to use hardware accelleration / the gpu.

for instance see here [CSS transition effect makes image blurry / moves image 1px, in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15464055/css-transition-effect-makes-image-blurry-moves-image-1px-in-chrome)

Comment: Thanks. So the `perspective` part does not matter? Is it the 'useless' part?

Comment: @HynekS the whole part is 'useless' as it shouldnt really change the result of the rendering, but is only added to force the browser to render it in a different pipeline.